# rancher supercede network policy for projects

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

I wish to setup pod that will access services in different projects in rancher's v2 kubernetes. (rancher setups network policy that pods can access pods in namespaces from same project)

That pod is custom ingress proxy that might be used in front of all projects in kube

Answer (score 2):

You can use "Flannel" network plugin instead of "Canal" while setting up the cluster. Work is <s>in progress</s> finished to provide enable/disable of the project network policies for Canal.

**Edit 1 (09/03/2018):**

https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/14462 has been resolved.